# Проверка на существование

Tags: php, mysql

Здравствуйте. Сделал проверку пользователей на существование в регистрации, вот такой скрипт

```
$search = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE mobPhone='.$mobPhone.' AND email='.$email.'");
$seachf = mysql_fetch_array($search);
if (empty($seachf)) {
```

}

А проблема в том, что он не обрабатывает условие, то есть если такой пользователь есть, то он все равно его регистрирует.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Лучше проверять количество, чем вытаскивать саму запись:

```
$search = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) cnt FROM users WHERE mobPhone='" . $mobPhone . "' AND email='" . $email . "'");
$seachf = mysql_fetch_array($search);

if($seachf['cnt'] == 0){
  echo 'такого пользователя нет';
}
```

Comment: @ua6xh, У Вас запрос к БД кривой :)

Comment: @ReinRaus - точняк) Сейчас поправим, спс.

Comment: Да, согласен, что кривой) Исправил) Точки убрал вообще, щас все норм работает.

Comment: Лучше делать select 1 where exists или limit 1

(извините за некропостофилию)

Answer (score 1):

У Вас запрос к БД кривой. Заострите внимание на изучении конкатенации строк в php и их обработку.    
Например, телефон 71234567890 и мыло a@b.c , тогда в MySQL уйдет такой запрос:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE mobPhone='.71234567890 .' AND email='.a@b.c.'
```

Естественно, что всегда нет выборки для такого запроса.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так

```
$search = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE mobPhone='".$mobPhone."' AND email='".$email."'");
$prov=0;
$prov=mysql_num_rows($search);
if ($prov>0)
 {
   // код если в запрос что-то нашел
 }
else
 {
  // код если запрос ничего не нашел
 }
```

Описание команды http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-num-rows.php